# html is not listed as support language vscode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm writing some HTML utilizing vscode and down at the bottom right shows the support language that vscode is utilizing. I click on it and HTML is not listed among the supported languages. The only one is HTML Liquid.

The problem is that when I highlight code follow with the keystroke to comment the code out, is commenting with HTML liquid syntax like so...
`{% comment %}Bootstrap{% endcomment %}`. I went to vscode website under the languages section, HTML, and is nothing I can find to solve this problem.

Do I need to install any extension to add support for HTML?

Comment: HTML support is built-in, you shouldn't need to install anything: http://i.imgur.com/c8FKNal.png Have you tried starting VSCode without extensions? (`code --disable-extensions`)

Comment: I had to uninstall Jekyll extension and Django extensions. The interesting thing is that when those extensions are installed, native HTML supports goes away and if I click in the very bottom right corner, native HTML is no longer there.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like a bug. Not sure if VSCode or those extensions are to blame.

Answer (score 0):

By default, vscode works fine. There might be some issue with plugins.

I had to uninstall Python Extension Pack which had 6 extensions including Django. After uninstalling it works fine.